# I am getting timed out using PHP-SDK

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get the count of the no of mutual friends I have with all my friends.

```
foreach($friends_list as $friend)
{   
    $id = $friend['id'];
    $name = $friend['name'];
    $arr = $facebook->api('/me/mutualfriends/'.$id);
    $arr = $arr['data'];
    $count = count($arr);
    $totalcount = $totalcount + $count;
    $i++;
    echo $id. "  " .$name . "  " . $count . "</br>";
}
```

But I am getting timed out like after getting data of around 20 frnds. How should I go about optimizing it?

Answer (score 1):

You getting timeout in your script because of configuration settings for [`max_execution_time`](http://php.net/max-execution-time) in `php.ini` and this can be easily avoided if you'll use something like this before running that long op:

```
set_time_limit(0);
// execute long running code...
```

Doing many requests to external services in a loop is bad and there is couple of way to improve your code to be much faster.

Option 1: You may use [Batch Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) for [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to run several requests (up to 50) at once.

Option 2: You may get `mutualfriends` connection in other direction (getting results for several friends at once).

```
https://graph.facebook.com/mutualfriends/YOUR_ID?ids=friend_1,friend_2,friend_n
```

This is generally the same as:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/friend_1/mutualfriends/YOUR_ID
https://graph.facebook.com/friend_2/mutualfriends/YOUR_ID
https://graph.facebook.com/friend_n/mutualfriends/YOUR_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting a `sleep` in that loop as to not overload the server.

e.g.

```
foreach( $friends_list as $friend )
{
    $id = $friend['id'];
    $name = $friend['name'];
    $arr = $facebook->api('/me/mutualfriends/'.$id);
    $arr = $arr['data'];
    $count = count($arr);
    $totalcount = $totalcount + $count;
    $i++;
    echo $id. " " .$name . " " . $count . "";

    usleep( 100000 );
}
```

To wait 100 milliseconds after each request.

Comment: The gateway received an invalid HTTP response or unexpected disconnect from the original server

Sill I am receiving this error.

Answer (score 0):

Update the 'max_execution_time' settings in your php.ini file. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the php.ini.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php